# Is there a continuous path through the complement of a family of closed sets in the unit square, if none touches both bottom and top?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I wonder whether the following claim is correct.

Consider a family of connected closed subsets of the unit square that (i) do not touch each other and (ii) contains its closure, in the sense that

- for any two points from two different sets, any path connecting the two points will contain a point that is not an element of any set of the family and
- if we select a sequence of points---all of which are elements of some set of the original family---then the limit of that sequence is also an element of some set of the original family. This rules out the family of rational coordinates.

If this family contains no closed set that touches both the bottom and the top of the square, then there is a path from the right side to the left side of the unit square that does not intersect with any of the closed sets (it goes through the complement of the family). The path has finite length.

Note the converse: If there are two connected closed subsets of the unit square, one touching the bottom and the top, and one touching the left and the right, then the sets intersect.

Comment: It seems you need another condition. The plane itself is a union of its points, which are non intersecting closed sets.

Comment: Thank you. This is of course true.

Comment: I edited the question accordingly. I don't allow closed sets that touch each other---basically, I want to merge any two touching sets.

Comment: I don't see the connection between the title and the body. The body doesn't contain the word "path". And I don't see that you've excluded Jakob Hansen's example. If I understand correctly what you mean by "touch each other", the one-point sets in the plane don't touch each other, and the limit property is clearly also satisfied.

Comment: In case your edit to the title was intended to address my above remark, I don't see how it does.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, ruling out "touching" needs a different condition.

Comment: Regarding the title: I updated the text to ask for a path---not a set---connecting the left and the right sides. Note that the existence of a set implies the existence of a path, since the boundaries of the closed set will be paths of finite length.

Comment: Imposing the intuitive notion of "no touching" is surprisingly difficult. Maybe you have a better idea.

Comment: I don't think the converse is a converse.  Let A = $[1/4,3/4] \times [0,1/4]\cup [ 1/4,3/4]\times[[3/4,1]$.  A is closed and touches top and bottom.  Let B = $[0,1/8]\times[3/8,5/8] \cup [7/8,1]\times[3/8,5/8]$.  B is closed and touches left and right.  A and B don't intersect.  But this doesn't, so far as I understand your question, counter your original proposal.

Comment: Your converse statement at the bottom is false, unless perhaps you want to speak about connected sets. (E.g. consider $A$ = one point from the top and one point from the bottom, and $B$ = one point from the left and one point from the right.)

Comment: "no touching" means disjoint.  Which for closed set means separated.  I think you want to read up on "separated" and "separable" (and "connected" for good measure.)

Comment: Fleablood: Yes, I meant connected closed sets.

Comment: "no touching" = there is an $\epsilon > 0$ such that for all x in A and all y in B, d(x,y) > epsilon.  This is equivalent (I think) to separate ($cl(A) \cap B = A \cap cl(B)) which for closed spaces means simply disjoint.  I think.  You do need to indicate the universe space is complete.  [0,1) and (1,2] are closed and separate and don't touch  in R - {1} but are not closed and do "touch" in R.

Comment: Fleablood: I would like to avoid too strong notions of being separated. Also, any two points from the unit square are separated, so the set of all points from the unit square is a family of separated closed sets.

Comment: Arrgh... you are right.  I think we need that between any two sets of the family there is a point not in the family.  I.e. for A,B in the family, x in A y in B there exists an a not in the family at all such that d(x,a)+d(a, y) = d(x,y).  okay that won't work for all other metric spaces but it will work for R^k.  Or maybe just disallow singletons.  Yeah,  just require the sets be closed and every point in a set is a limit point of the set.  i.e no singletons.

Comment: Hmmmm....Might boil down to being equivalent of showing that a closed interval is not the union of more than one disjoint closed intervals. Which I believe is true.

Comment: Fleablood: I cannot rule out singletons, unfortunately.